# Best way to generate identifiers?

Tags: u-sql

I will incrementally insert rows to a table. This table stores sales facts, and has some columns that will be used to define a identifier: business id (int), product name (string), product price (float). E.g. <1, heineken, 1.0>, <1, heineken, 22.99>.

Certainly, these values will be used in joins. When thinking the SQL way, I would create a hashed column using those columns. This way, I would be able to optimize some queries.

How about data lake and u-sql? Should I calculate the hash on insert? Should I leave it as is? Should I simply concatenate the values and create a big string?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While U-SQL supports clustering and distribution schemes on multiple columns, you probably could gain some additional performance in your joins if you find an efficient value to do your equi-join comparison. So you could calculate a hash or concatenate.

However, I think finding the right distribution scheme and clustering is the better "bang for your buck".

And, more importantly, please do not incrementally insert small number of rows, but use bulk insertion of many rows at the same time (e.g., daily or weekly). And regularly rebuild the table or table partition to avoid table fragmentation that will have a much bigger impact on your query performance.

Comment: Thank you, Michael Rys. I got a little bit lost regarding the bulk append. Could you send me some resource regarding it? As I understood, when working with tables in data lake the only way of inserting to the table is by using the INSERT command. FYI, I am processing data saved to data lake from event hubs. The only way I am able to process it is by doing a daily EXTRACT from its files and INSERT to the desired table. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I mean is that you INSERT many rows at the same time, preferably once a day or so, instead of one row at a time... I clarify it in the answer.

Comment: Michael Rys, I appreciate your help! I am still learning from ADL, but eventually I will get there! Thank you!

Comment: One more tip: You can try out the performance of multi-column joins vs computed "hash" column joins by testing it locally... it will not give you the scale-out nor the exact cluster behavior (since you use different specs), but a performance comparison of the two approaches nevertheless.

Comment: That is what I am attempting to do. I was running some tests in production and spending 100 usd/day. Ouch!